# Custom counter in tasks environment

Tags: counters, tasks

I am using a custom counter to generate the labels in a `\NewTasksEnvironment` (package `tasks` v.1.1a). This is the approach I had chosen since I use this counter elsewhere (I need to increment and decrement its value for other purposes).

I honestly wouldn't mind using the built-in `tasks` counter, but I actually don't know its name and I'm not sure if fiddling around with it in the rest of the code would cause issues, at this point.

**Question 1** What is the name of the built-in counter used in `\NewTasksEnvironment` if I use the default `label=\alph*)`?

**Question 2** See MWE code below. I use `\refstepcounter` in the `label=` option of `\NewTasksEnvironment` which seems to cause the counter to be incremented **twice** at every label (see output below, after code). Adding a 14th item causes a `Counter too large` error since it exceeds the 26 alphabetical values available. If I remove the `\refstepcounter`, the counter's value always remains at 0, so it appears as though the `label=(...)` code is being "called" twice. How can I fix this behaviour to ensure the counter is only incremented once?

By the way, this (code below) used to work with the `tasks` package v0.9 (so before last year's v1.0 update).

**Code**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tasks}

\newcounter{subquest}
\setcounter{subquest}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesubquest}{\alph{subquest})}

\NewTasksEnvironment%
  [%
      label = \refstepcounter{subquest}\thesubquest,%
  ]%
  {lsubquestions}[\squest](1)

\begin{document}

\begin{lsubquestions}
  \squest Subquestion 1
  \squest Subquestion 2
  \squest Subquestion 3
  \squest Subquestion 4
  \squest Subquestion 5
  \squest Subquestion 6
  \squest Subquestion 7
  \squest Subquestion 8
  \squest Subquestion 9
  \squest Subquestion 10
  \squest Subquestion 11
  \squest Subquestion 12
  \squest Subquestion 13
  %\squest Subquestion 14
\end{lsubquestions}

\end{document}
```

**Output**:

```
b) Subquestion 1
d) Subquestion 2
f) Subquestion 3
h) Subquestion 4
j) Subquestion 5
l) Subquestion 6
n) Subquestion 7
p) Subquestion 8
r) Subquestion 9
t) Subquestion 10
v) Subquestion 11
x) Subquestion 12
z) Subquestion 13
```

Comment: Why can't you simply use `label=\alph*)` with your environment?

Comment: I either need to use `label=\alph*)`, in which case I must know the internal counter's name because I use this value elsewhere (and I don't know if it'll work), or I can use a custom counter as mentioned in the question, which is the easiest option for me since the rest of the code is already written using this approach.

Comment: `tasks.sty` defines only a single counter: `\newcounter {task}`.  (See https://github.com/cgnieder/tasks/blob/master/tasks.sty)  There are various `expl3` integers running around, but I think that's the main counter within the environment.

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling tells me that this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but I am going to answer anyway.

---

With v1.2 there are two ways how a different counter than the default one can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tasks}[2020/03/21]
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcounter{test}

% first version:
\NewTasksEnvironment[
  label = \tasksifmeasuringF{\refstepcounter{test}}A\thetest ,
  label-width = 13pt
]{testa}

% second version:
\NewTasksEnvironment[
  counter = test ,
  label = B\arabic* ,
  label-width = 13pt
]{testb}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{testa}
  \task one
  \task two\label{testa}
  \task three
  \task four
\end{testa}

\begin{testb}
  \task one
  \task two
  \task three\label{testb}
  \task four
\end{testb}
\end{multicols}

See \ref{testa} and \ref{testb}

\end{document}
```

[image]